# How to UPDATE a field from a SELECT table using JOIN

Tags: mysql, sql, sql-update, mariadb

I have three tables.

**inspectionreport**

```
+----------+-----------------+------+
| ReportID | InspectionID_id | Date |
+----------+-----------------+------+
```

inspectionreport has `ReportID` PK, `InspectionID_id` FK, and date field `Date`.

**inspection**

```
+--------------+------------+
| InspectionID | PartID_id  |
+--------------+------------+
```

inspection has `InspectionID` PK and `PartID_id` FK.

**part**

```
+--------+---------------+
| partID | LastInspected |
+--------+---------------+
```

part has a `partID` PK and date field `LastInspected` which is null by default.

What I want to do is fill `LastInspected` with **THE LATEST** `Date` for the relevant part.

So far I've tried using this SELECT query:

```
SELECT * 
FROM moorings_inspectionreport 
JOIN moorings_inspection 
     ON moorings_inspectionreport.InspectionID_id = moorings_inspection.InspectionID;
```

I figured I could use this to check if `PartID_id` matched `partID` as it's now only two tables. But I'm so confused as to how to pull this off as I'm quite unfamiliar with sql queries.

I also want to put this update into a daily running event that updates for every entry in the part table. So for me that adds a whole other level of confusion.

Comment: Just a note, tables have _columns_, not _fields_.

Comment: Make it easy to assist you, add some sample table data and the expected result - as formatted text, not images. Take a look at [mcve].

Comment: Sorry I'm relatively new to the whole concept. Is it still a column if I want to refer to a single field/cell/entry and not every row in the column? Because in this specific scenario I want to update only one row at a time in part from the LastInspected column.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

By joining the 2 tables `inspection` and `inspectionreport` and grouping by partid you can get the last `lastinspected` for each partid.
Then join to `part` and update:

```
update part p
inner join (
  select i.partid, max(r.date) date
  from inspection i 
  inner join inspectionreport r on r.inspectionid = i.inspectionid
  group by i.partid
) t on p.partid = t.partid
set p.lastinspected = t.date
```

Comment: Thanks this certainly looks like it could be what I'm looking for! I'm a bit confused by your notation though I'm wondering if you could explain it to me. What are `p`, `i`, `r` and `t`? Are these variables you have assigned? Sorry I'm very unfamiliar with SQL.

Comment: p,i,r, and t are aliases of the tables (for example p is the alias of the table part and t is the alias of the subquery). You can do without them (except from t) but using aliases is common practice that not only reduces the code, but also it makes it more readable if you get used to it.

Comment: So saying p.partid is the same as typing part.partid? If I understand correctly this is just assigning a shorthand name essentially?

Comment: Exactly. And t.partid and t.date refer to the columns of the subquery that returns all the last dates.

Comment: Perfect! I just tested this and it works exactly like I asked. Fantastic answer thank you so much.